# How to faster startup Jhipster application

Tags: javascript, jhipster

Starting or refreshing my Jhipster application (version 4.5.2) takes depending on the setup from 6s up to 40s.
According to Google-analytics, a huge part of the time is spent on the vendor.dll.js file.

[Screenshot of GoogleAnalytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQnsw.png)

I would like the application to quickly load the main/landingpage whilst the rest of the application is beeing loaded in the background.
How could that be achieved?
Is it possible to split the JavaScript files into smaller ones to get prioritiset loading?

Comment: I'm using jhipster version 4.5.2 at the moment

Comment: Are you running in prod profile with a prod build?

Comment: yes, i do. I found that it makes not a real noticable difference timewise though

Comment: Could you try 4.5.5? AOT is supposed to work and also lazy loading of admin module.

Comment: I tried 4.5.6 with basically the same result. I actually didn't find how to choose AOT/ JIT or lazy loading..

Comment: You don't have to choose, it should be already configured in webpack config files. vendor.dll contains all 3rd party dependencies, without AOT it contains also angular compiler which is big. Didn't you notice any smaller size of your bundle?.

Comment: It could have been too early, there is an issue with AOT that seems to have been fixed and should be in next release. See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/5952